# Add third Party Frameworks in a project in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es, ios-frameworks

I am trying to use the **NinevehGL framework** in my iPad app. I've added the framework to my Xcode project. However, when I run my app,it executes successfully.

Note: After i installed the NinevehGl.pkg, The NinevehGl framework is shows in the project Template itself.

[image]

Am selecting this template means automatically it creates some frameworks in Link Binary with Libraries.

[image]

But my issue is: While am running the same Xcode project in other mac, it crash. Because other mac's am not installed this package. So i want to add this framework in the project itself. How to add this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with there are a few frameworks we will need to add.

Do this by first selecting your projects main file in the project navigator pane.

Make sure your projects target is selected, and under **Build Phases** click ‘**Link Binaries with Libraries**’.

[image]

Use the **+** at the bottom of this display and add the **QuartsCore**  and **OpenGLES** frameworks.

Next, using the ‘**Add Other**’ button, navigate to your downloaded **NinevehGL folder** and import the **NinevehGL.framework**.

[image]

Now onto the code…….import NinevehGL into your header (.h) file,

```
#import <NinevehGL/NinevehGL.h>
```

add the delegate to your @interface, if this is missing your drawview method will never get called.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <NGLViewDelegate>;
```

Answer Referenced from [icodeblog](http://www.icodeblog.com/2012/09/07/3856/)

Comment: You are correct. but i installed Nineveh.pkg file know. so it installed in my mac itself. but i want to use the NinevehGL.framework into library class. then only i can access this framework into other mac machine.

Comment: To make "Ninevehgl" apps run on every Mac, you do not need to install the Nineveh.pkg file. Instead of, just do what I mentioned.Copy & paste the "NinevehGL.framework" folder from downloaded NinevehGL folder to your project directory. and add QuartsCore and OpenGLES frameworks. then go to 'Build Phases' click ‘Link Binaries with Libraries’, click ‘Add Other’ button,select the pasted "NinevehGL.framework" folder from ur project source directory. Thats it. now you can import <NinevehGL/NinevehGL.h> and transfer the project to any machine. It should run in any machines without any modifications.