# table view with images which are loaded from server in iphone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

Hi I am developing IOS application. My application contains table view with image as part of my table. I am loading my image from server. It is working fine. But problem with my table view is once I scroll my table view it is start flickering my images. That mean it showing wrong image for some time after some time it shows right images. this behaviour continues when I scroll. Is there any need to explicitly call any object to nil or release some cell object or holding some cell objects. My cell for table view looks like :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MediaContentCell";

MediaContentCell *cell = (MediaContentCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = (MediaContentCell *)[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

VideoDataModel *videoData = [_mediaContentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.mediaTitle.text = videoData.title;
cell.mediaSubtitle.text = videoData.shortdescription;

NSMutableArray *posters = videoData.poster;

dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("ImageQue",NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^
{
    UIImage *image;
    if(!posters)
    {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dummyprog_large1.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        for(int index = 0 ; index < posters.count; index++)
        {
            PosterDataModel *posterData = [posters objectAtIndex:index];
            if([posterData.postertype isEqualToString:POSTER_TYPE_LANDSCAPE])
            {
                 image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:posterData.posterurl]]];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        cell.mediaPicture.image = image;
    });
});

[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

return cell;
}
```

Is there any one can help me for this? Need some help Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use - [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

```
     [cell.imageView sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad];
     [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

I am using this framework and Its working fine for me.

Comment: this framework is provided by platform itself or we have to include it externally?

Comment: We have to include it externally.

Comment: Is this library project or just framework. Mean I am not able to include it. How to do that? I am android background guy bit new to IOS

Comment: its third party framework. you need to add into your project.
[check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721668/add-third-party-frameworks-in-a-project-in-ios)

Comment: I tried to include this library project but it not working for me. There no .framework or .a file inside that project. then I just copied sdwebimage folder inside my project and tried to use it but still it is not working. Can you please help me to figure this out.

Comment: sample code of that library project also gives error.

Comment: It is not recognizing setImageWithUrl method

Comment: @nilkash -I was busy with my work so, I couldn't reply you on time. Finally, you got the answer how to add framework?

Answer (score 1):

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:yourDefaultImgUrl];

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourServerImageUrl];      
        if (imageData){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 UITableViewCell *updateCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];          
                 if (updateCell)
                updateCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            });
        }
    });
```

It helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

It's the reuse mechanism that causes your problem

Say, if your table view has 1000 cells to display, and 5 cells are visible on the screen at a time, iOS will only create 6 UITableViewCell objects in the memory.

In your code, the image will be loaded asynchronously from the network, and then set to the [mediaPicture] belonging to the cell at an index path, but when you scroll the table view, because of the reuse mechanism, the [cell.mediaPicture] might not be correctly related to the index path anymore, and the downloaded image will be wrongly set.

You can take a look at this question about the reuse mechanism:

[UITableViewCell - Understanding "reuseable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330038/uitableviewcell-understanding-reuseable)

And Amol's answer is exactly the solution for your case.

Comment: I was also using same dispatch_asyc.Only difference was dispatch_queue type. Is that the making difference? I am using `dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("ImageQue",NULL);` and Amol suggesting `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)`. Will it make difference? Thank you for kind help. Willing to get deeper answer. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it's not the queue type that cause your problem, it's because you didn't check for the correct cell before assigning the downloaded image, which exactly what Amol's code does in this block: 
_UITableViewCell *updateCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];          
                 if (updateCell)..._